# Identify VBA UDF Bottlneck

Tags: vba, excel, performance, runtime

In my worksheet, I have four different categories. For each category, there are 
3~5 different prices. There are other attributes as well. As a result, each categories are duplicated many times and there are 30,000 rows in total. The first row of the worksheet have all the column names. Each category spans over consecutive rows. Therefore, I wrote the following function to identify "blocks" and calculate the min of the "blocks".

[Example Image of How Cat Blocks Look Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPlmL.png)

```
    Public Function blockMin(rng_temp As Range) As Integer

        Dim currRow As Long
        currRow = rng_temp.Row

        'Find Category col
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim cabin_col As Long
        Dim price_col As Long


        For Each rng In Range("1:1")
            If rng.Value = "Cat" Then
                cat_col = rng.Column
            End If
            If rng.Value = "Price" Then
                pric_col = rng.Column
            End If
        Next rng

        Dim cat_col_char, price_col As String
        cat_col_char = Number2Letter(cat_col)
        price_col_char = Number2Letter(price_col)

        ' Find last row of the usedRange    
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = findLastRow()

        'Where the block is for each cat
        Dim startRow, endRow As Long
        startRow = rng_temp.Row
        endRow = rng_temp.Row

         'Find Top
        Do While startRow >= 2
            If Range(cat_col_char & startRow).Value <> Range(cat_col_char & currRow) Then
                startRow = startRow + 1
                Exit Do
            End If
            startRow = startRow - 1
        Loop

        If startRow = 1 Then startRow = 2   ' at the very top

         'Find Bottom
        Do While endRow <= lastRow - 1
            If Range(cat_col_char & endRow).Value <> Range(cat_col_char & currRow) Then
                endRow = endRow - 1
                Exit Do
            End If
            endRow = endRow + 1
        Loop

        If endRow = lastRow - 1 Then endRow = lastRow ' at the very bottom

        'Return min of the block
        Dim block As Range
        Set block = Range(price_col_char & startRow & ":" & price_col_char & endRow)

        blockMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(block)

    End Function
```

When I call the formula for a single cell, it is pretty fast. However, I have to call the UDF for 30,000 cells and that takes up to five minutes for every single calculation refresh. I was wondering if there are some room of improvements for run-time. Or, if there is a better way to work around it with built-in formula.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Might be worth putting `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, fixing your undeclared/typo variables, then reposting your code.

Comment: `For Each rng In Range("1:1")` - you're checking ~16000 cells (twice) for every call - you should exit the loop when  `cat_col` and `price_col` are >0

Comment: I'd guess this would be *much* faster if you turn it into a Sub instead of using it as a UDF - there's a lot of repetition going on for each call.

Comment: From a brief glance and not being 100% clear from your description of what the code is meant to achieve (I still cannot picture what a block is), you may benefit by using a Pivot Table across your data.

Comment: The block is shown as a link in the body of the question. Sorry that I just started to use this account so I wasn't authorized to post images, but only URLs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would be a little faster:

```
Public Function blockMin(rng_temp As Range) As Integer 'double?

    Dim sht As Worksheet, rS As Long, rE As Long, cat, v
    Dim hdrs, i As Long
    Dim cat_col As Long, price_col As Long

    Set sht = rng_temp.Worksheet '<<< scope all references to this sheet
                                 ' or you'll get odd results when a different
                                 ' sheet is active
    rS = rng_temp.Row
    rE = rS

    'Find headers
    hdrs = sht.Range("A1").Resize(1, 100).Value 'limit your search range
    For i = 1 To UBound(hdrs, 2)
        v = hdrs(1, i)

        If cat_col = 0 And v = "Cat" Then cat_col = i
        If price_col = 0 And v = "Price" Then price_col = i

        If cat_col > 0 And price_col > 0 Then
            cat = rng_temp.EntireRow.Cells(cat_col).Value
            If Len(cat) > 0 Then
                'find start/end rows
                Do While rS > 1 And sht.Cells(rS, cat_col) = cat
                    rS = rS - 1
                Loop
                Do While sht.Cells(rE, cat_col) = cat
                    rE = rE + 1
                Loop

                blockMin = Application.Min(sht.Range(sht.Cells(rS + 1, price_col), _
                                                     sht.Cells(rE - 1, price_col)))
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: what are `rS` and `rE` apart from randomly named variables?

Comment: Not random, just short: "rowStart", "rowEnd"

Comment: OK - so why so short instead of the descriptive name?

Comment: Because that's what I preferred at the time I wrote that code?  It's not *so* indecipherable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Is there a way for me to get over the loop part? I assume that is the bottleneck.

Comment: The real bottleneck is having to repeat the same calculations over and over for each line in each category, and each time you refresh the sheet.   If you created a sub to refresh these values it would be much faster.  Are the unique category values always clustered together, and what's the typical number of lines per category?

Comment: There are four categories, alternating throughout 30,000 rows. But in each "block", there will only be one category - that's how I define block. Typically, each category has 3,4 or 5 rows before going into the next category.

Comment: Thanks! I did, but it was still taking longer than I thought a UDF would. I would probably go with Sub/Python instead.

Comment: Moving the range to variant array would speed this up a lot